# React-native expo-video-player in Web Browser

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

So I have the following problem. I installed the expo-video-player from https://github.com/ihmpavel/expo-video-player and added the necessary dependencies. And while everything works fine on Android, my app crashes in the web browser. So my question is, if this behaviour is expected or not?

For reference, here is my usage of the Videoplayer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import  VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'

export const VideoPlayerCustom = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <VideoPlayer
          videoProps={{
            shouldPlay: false,
            resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_COVER,
            source: {
              uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
            },
          }}
          inFullscreen={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

And this is the error message from the console:

```
VM56 bundle.js:6227 The above error occurred in the <WithDefaultProps(VideoPlayer)> component:
    in WithDefaultProps(VideoPlayer) (at VideoPlayerCustom.js:13)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (at VideoPlayerCustom.js:12)
    in VideoPlayerCustom (at MainPage.js:48)
    in div (created by View)
    ...
    ...
```

In this line:

```
  var _useNetInfo = Object(_react_native_community_netinfo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__["useNetInfo"])() <- here is the error with the message Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function,
      isConnected = _useNetInfo.isConnected;
```

I would appreciate any advice also regarding the best practice of implementing a video player with custom controlls for an app in react-native/expo.

Answer (score 0):

package `NetInfo`, which is installed with `Expo` is locked in version `4.6.x`.  WebSupport has been added in version `5.x`.

You need to wait till `Expo SDK 37`, which will include support for `NetInfo` version `5.x`.

You can check more on Github https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo